# issue with importing user-defined package in java

Tags: java, import, package, .class-file

I want to import the `.class` files in a package into another file. The directory structure is as shown below.

```
|-lib-(contains some jar files)
|
|-XYZ-|
|     |-CT-(package that contains some .class files)
|     |
|     |-B.java
|
|-A.java
```

How can i import the `.class` files in "CT" package into `B.java` and how to import them into `A.java`. How to provide the class path and stuff. Also I want to set classpath to jar files in lib as well...So how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The importing of one class into another class is done at the time of coding.

From the code, it looks like there is no parent-child relationship.

To import in B.java write `import XYZ.CT.<class name without .class extension>`

To import in A.java write `import XYZ.B`

To set the classpath while running:

java -classpath path to lib with all the jar files one by one separated by : for unix and ; for windows and then append the path to the parent folder of lib folder to add all the classes to the classpath.

e.g. for unix:

```
java -cp lib/a.jar:lib/b.jar;<parent folder of lib> <main program class name with complete package>
```